# unit testing viewmodel in silverlight MVVM pattern

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, mvvm

I need to do unit testing of view model in Silverlight application with prism. Here the view model that need to test has only one constructor which is taking `Dispatcher` and `EventAggregator` as parameters:

```
public MyViewModel( IDispatcher dispatcher, IEventAggregator aggregator )
        : base(dispatcher, aggregator) {...}
```

How to mock `Dispatcher` and `EventAggregator` parameters in my code in order to create an instance of my view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ctor arguments are abstracted by interfaces, so for your UnitTest you can write two mocks that implement one interface each and use those...

```
public class DispatcherMock : IDispatcher { ... }
public class EventAggregatorMock : IEventAggregator { ... }

var sut = new MyViewModel(new DispatcherMock(), new EventAggregatorMock());
```

...or you can add [`moq.silverlight`](https://code.google.com/p/moq/) (the mock framework I'm using) and let the framework handle the interface details, you don't have to implement it yourself:

```
var dispatcherMock = new Mock<IDispatcher>();
var aggregatorMock = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();
var sut = new MyViewModel(dispatcherMock.Object, aggregatorMock.Object);
```